# How do I shift the <include> layout to the bottom of the view

Tags: android

I am trying to push my included view to the bottom of the layout, however I am not having any luck.Currently it's placed at the top of the layout.The code for the same is as follows:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@color/altercolor2"
    android:clickable="true"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <include
        layout="@layout/layout_grid_details_header_view"
        android:visibility="gone" />

     <include layout="@layout/last_updated_time" />

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/markets_column_names"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@color/black"
        android:paddingBottom="3dp" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/markets_column_name1"
            android:layout_width="75dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/markets_column_name2"
            android:textSize="12sp"
            android:gravity="right" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/markets_column_name2"
            android:layout_width="75dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/markets_column_name3"
            android:textSize="12sp"
            android:gravity="right" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/markets_column_name3"
            android:layout_width="85dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:textSize="12sp"
            android:paddingRight="6dp"
            android:gravity="right" />
    </RelativeLayout>

    <com.handmark.pulltorefresh.library.PullToRefreshListView
        android:id="@+id/markets_grid_list"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />



       <include layout="@layout/loading_no_results" />

</LinearLayout>
```

The main thing I am looking to switch at the bottom of the list is :          `<include layout="@layout/last_updated_time" />`
so, I tried           I also tried setting paddingbottom andlayout_below: relavitive layout id, and tried setting layout_gravity = bottom and gravity = botttom, still no luck.Any clue how to push this at the bottom of the view such that it still remains visible even if the list is long, but at the bottom of the view, like overlapping the list view at the bottom.

Thanks!Justin

Answer (score 3):

Give `layout_width` and `layout_height` attribute to 'include tag', then you can give it any of it's parent tag attribute

Answer (score 0):

Since the root `layout` is a `LinearLayout` with a vertical `orientation`, it is going to be drawn in the order you have them. Simply putting it as the last `View` in the xml would draw it below the previous `View` then you could play with margin, padding, whatever to get it to be where you want.

A better option would be to change the root `layout` to a `RelativeLayout` and give the `View` in question the property

```
     android:layout_alignParentBottom="true
```

You may have to adjust some properties of other `Views` to get exactly what you want but its hard to say without seeing an image of how it should look. Also, `android:layout_below=""` wouldn't work with its parent `layout` being a `LinearLayout`...that is only a property for `RelativeLayout`.

**Edit with code example**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@color/altercolor2"
    android:clickable="true" >

    <include
        layout="@layout/layout_grid_details_header_view"
        android:visibility="gone" />

     <include layout="@layout/last_updated_time"
         android:layout_width="wrap_content"
         android:layout_height="wrap_content"
         android:layout_alignParentBottom="true" />

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/markets_column_names"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@color/black"
        android:paddingBottom="3dp" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/markets_column_name1"
            android:layout_width="75dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/markets_column_name2"
            android:textSize="12sp"
            android:gravity="right" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/markets_column_name2"
            android:layout_width="75dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/markets_column_name3"
            android:textSize="12sp"
            android:gravity="right" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/markets_column_name3"
            android:layout_width="85dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:textSize="12sp"
            android:paddingRight="6dp"
            android:gravity="right" />
    </RelativeLayout>

    <com.handmark.pulltorefresh.library.PullToRefreshListView
        android:id="@+id/markets_grid_list"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />



       <include layout="@layout/loading_no_results" />

</RelativeLayout >
```

Comment: It shows invalid param in linear layout , any other way to do it?

Comment: You shouldn't have a `LinearLayout` anymore. It should be a `RelativeLayout`. I will update with more code

Comment: making it a relativelayout messes up the top headers, which disappear and the last_updated_time doesnt work either, not sure how to modify the current code

Comment: That's why I said you may have to modify properties of the other `Views` since I don't know exactly how it should look. [RelativeLayout Docs](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/RelativeLayout.html) show all available properties. Use `android:layout_alignParentTop="true"` for whatever you want at the top then whatever you want below that use `android:layout_below="@id/idOfViewAboveThis"`

Comment: And what do you mean by "it doesn't work"? Does it not show, not show properly, etc...

Comment: it doesnt show, the headers disappear and the last updated time doesnt show at all

Comment: What do you mean by your "headers"? Is that what's inside the inner `RelativeLayout`? Check that you have content in your `include` layout...I have no idea what's in there.

Answer (score 0):

Try using frame layout : make your current linearlayout as first child (removing the include  view that u want to move to bottom). Make the include view as second view and set its layout_gravity to bottom.

Comment: can you explain it programmatically?

Comment: Following is the structure that I tried to emphasize above : `<FrameLayout android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="fill_parent"> <LinearLayout (as given by you above,Just remove the INCLUDED layout that you want to move to bottom> </LinearLayout> <include layout="@layout/last_updated_time" android:layout_gravity="bottom"/> </FrameLayout>` I hope this helps. I have omitted some obvious things as my aim was just to show you the structure. Sorry, the code is not properly formatted. I am trying to figure out how to do so.