# How to set my webview boundaries?

Tags: android

I have a webview app, that uses js code files from assets. The issue I am having is that I have the game files in js that it takes up half the web browser. Now when I use the same as a webview in my app, it seems to be scrollable and half the view gets cut off from the screen which is scrollable. Is there a way I can restrict the boundaries of the webview and also force my webview to show the entire content of the webpage I am displaying? The following is my webview code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<WebView  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/webview"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
/>
```

Do I need to add this in a layout? If so, how do I go about it? 
Here is my java code:

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Window;
import android.view.WindowManager;
import android.webkit.WebView;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
        getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN, WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        WebView webview = (WebView)findViewById(R.id.webview);
        webview.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        webview.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/index.htm");
    }
}
```

Any changes required to the source files?

Thanks!
Justin

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this:

```
WebView webview = (WebView)findViewById(R.id.webview);
webView.setInitialScale(1);
webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
webView.getSettings().setLoadWithOverviewMode(true);
webView.getSettings().setUseWideViewPort(true);
webView.setScrollBarStyle(WebView.SCROLLBARS_OUTSIDE_OVERLAY);
webView.setScrollbarFadingEnabled(false);
webview.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/index.htm");
```

**UPDATE:**

You can toggle [Hardware Acceleration](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/graphics/hardware-accel.html) to make it faster.

& add this

```
webview.getSettings().setRenderPriority(RenderPriority.HIGH);
webview.getSettings().setCacheMode(WebSettings.LOAD_NO_CACHE);
```

Comment: perfect thanks, however, do you have any clue why its damn slow, any way to speed it up ?

Comment: on last question, how do i stop it from zooming everytime i click on the game , i tried webview.getSettings().setSupportZoom(false);, but it still zooms

Comment: thanks, do you happen to have any idea about this issue? it's pretty complicated so far:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18382510/how-do-i-fix-the-password-username-authentication-in-my-code?noredirect=1#comment27114067_18382510

Comment: ill try to answer it there